# Java: variable used in run method, initialized in for loop is not recognized in for loop's statement

Tags: java, for-loop

```
/*
 * File: Countdown.java
 * ----------------------
 * This program counts backwards from the value  START
 * to zero, as in the countdown preceding a rocket launch.
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class Countdown extends ConsoleProgram  {

    public void run () {
        for (int t = START; t >= 0; t-- ); {
            println(t);
        }
        println ("Liftoff!");
    }
/* Specifies the value from which to start the countdown.*/

    private static final int START = 10;
}
```

My problem is that the (t) in the  following statement is not recognized as a variable:

```
println(t);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for (int t = START; t >= 0; t-- ); {
                                 ^
    println(t);
}
```

to

```
for (int t = START; t >= 0; t--) {
    println(t);
}
```

The `;` closed the `for` statement, which means the following `{}` block was not part of the loop, so `t` wasn't defined in the scope of that block.

Comment: Thank you so much :) i'm obviously new :)

Answer (score 0):

(This is arguably a comment on [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34249658/1798593), but has to be posted as an answer to get the necessary formatting.)

You should use a Java-aware editor, and reformat regularly using it, but especially when you do not understand an error. I reformatted the code from the question using Eclipse. Here is the result:

```
for (int t = START; t >= 0; t--)
  ;
{
  println(t);
}
```

The significance of the ";", and the fact that the block is at the same level as the for-loop are both hidden by the original formatting and put front-and-center by the reformatting.

Comment: I use Eclipse myself. Never used a reformatting option. I am new, just trying to follow a book's exercises.